# How to prevent emails being sent with fake accounts in domain

Tags: email, smtp, spoofing

Short version: What can be done to prevent emails being sent from our SMTP mail server using fake accounts that do not really exist in the domain?

Longer version: We use Plesk to manage our site hosted on a Windows VPS. By enabling SMTP logging on MailEnable, I notice that a lot of emails are being sent with accounts that do not exist in the domain. I reproduce below a small portion of the log. Here `stolav-gw4@ourDomain.com`, `tango@ourDomain.com` are accounts that do not exist in our domain. What can be done to prevent such emails from being sent?

Things I have already tried and haven't stopped these:

- I already have set the SPF record entry. The entry is: `v=spf1 a mx -all`
- I have changed all the passwords. That hasn't helped.
- I have enabled DKIM
- I ran the following virus/malware detectors and they found nothing: VirusTotal Website Check, MSERT.exe from Microsoft, MSRT.exe from Microsoft

```
2021-02-17 06:00:02 212.70.149.71 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1228 AUTH {blank} 334+UGFzc3dvcmQ6 WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 18 38 stolav-gw4@ourDomain.com
2021-02-17 06:00:03 212.70.149.71 SMTP-IN - 104.128.234.235 1296 RSET RSET 250+Requested+mail+action+okay,+completed WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 43 6 -
2021-02-17 06:00:03 212.70.149.85 SMTP-IN - 104.128.234.235 1448 QUIT QUIT 221+Service+closing+transmission+channel WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 42 6 tango@ourDomain.com
2021-02-17 06:00:04 87.246.7.242 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1876 EHLO EHLO+User 250-ourDomain.com+[87.246.7.242],+this+server+offers+5+extensions WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 242 11 -
2021-02-17 06:00:04 212.70.149.85 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1848 AUTH {blank} 334+UGFzc3dvcmQ6 WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 18 34 tango@ourDomain.com
2021-02-17 06:00:04 212.70.149.71 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1228 AUTH c3RvbGF2LWd3NEAxMjM= 535+Invalid+Username+or+Password WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 34 22 stolav-gw4@ourDomain.com
2021-02-17 06:00:04 212.70.149.71 SMTP-IN - 104.128.234.235 1296 AUTH AUTH+LOGIN 334+VXNlcm5hbWU6 WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 18 12 -
2021-02-17 06:00:05 87.246.7.242 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1876 RSET RSET 250+Requested+mail+action+okay,+completed WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 43 6 -
2021-02-17 06:00:05 212.70.149.71 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1228 QUIT QUIT 221+Service+closing+transmission+channel WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 42 6 stolav-gw4@ourDomain.com
2021-02-17 06:00:05 212.70.149.85 SMTP-IN - our.ip.address.here 1848 AUTH Y3Zibm0xMjM= 535+Invalid+Username+or+Password WIN-DFQOE4PNR36 34
```

Comment: Interestingly, I see the same messages, and it is for the same IP! 
<pre>
    statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtps:212.70.149.71) at Mar 26 01:15:22
</pre>
I wonder, what does the above exactly mean, and what additional measures I have to take?

Comment: I had to ban this IP, it tried every minute `warning: unknown[212.70.149.71]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure`

Answer (score 0):

Start using a proper DMARC record in your DNS: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/create-dmarc-record
You would probably want the reject policy probably `reject: tells receiving email servers to reject the email if DMARC check fails`

Might want to read all the parts on that site. I used it once to setup my mail server and it's very informative.
That IP that abuses your mail is known for doing that. My logs:

```
Mar 25 04:34:12 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: warning: unknown[212.70.149.71]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Mar 25 04:34:18 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[212.70.149.71]
Mar 25 04:34:18 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: disconnect from unknown[212.70.149.71] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 commands=2/3
Mar 25 04:35:27 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: connect from unknown[212.70.149.71]
Mar 25 04:35:37 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[212.70.149.71]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Mar 25 04:36:05 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: warning: unknown[212.70.149.71]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Mar 25 04:36:10 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[212.70.149.71]
Mar 25 04:36:10 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: disconnect from unknown[212.70.149.71] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 commands=2/3
Mar 25 04:37:20 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: connect from unknown[212.70.149.71]
Mar 25 04:37:30 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[212.70.149.71]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Mar 25 04:37:58 main postfix/smtps/smtpd[35405]: warning: unknown[212.70.149.71]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
```

Which is repeated many, many times. No e-mails are sent from that IP, though.
Tried blocking that IP in the firewall but that didn't seem to work :? - Would like to know why, though, so if anyone knows, would like to know!

Information about it may be on one of those pages. Not sure because it's been a while, and don't have the time myself at this precise moment to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party programs;

- RdpGuard detects and blocks invalid connection attempts (RDP, SMTP, POP ...) using Windows firewall
- gykkSPAM (antispam filter) filters incoming and outgoing emails using local postoffices and authentication types